# How to Extract Two Columns of Data in R

Tags: r

I have to extract two columns from this data set (Cars93 on MASS) and create a separate folder consisting only of the two columns MPG.highway and EngineSize.  How do I go about doing this?

You can look at Cars93 on Mass and just get the first ten rows to see it.

Comment: Just use column names or index to extract the columns from the data.frame

Answer (score 5):

You can create a subset using the names directly using the `subset` function or alternately,

```
new_df <- Cars93[,c("MPG.highway","EngineSize")]
#or
new_df <- subset(Cars93, keep = c("MPG.highway","EngineSize"))
```